# Picasso showing blue red and green arrows on top corner

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, picasso

I am using picasso to fire up an image in imageView.

Here is the code

```
    ImageUtils.setImageFromUrl(app.selectedRing.getMainPicture(), imageView, MainActivity.this);


public static void setImageFromUrl(final String url, final ImageView imgView, final Context mContext)
    {
        Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(url)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .fit().centerInside().placeholder(null)
                .into(imgView, new Callback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError()
                    {
                        Picasso.with(mContext)
                                .load(url)
                                .fit().centerInside()
                                .into(imgView, new Callback()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess()
                                    {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError()
                                    {
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
    }
```

What i get is 
[image]
The problem is the blue arrow in left top corner, Sometimes its red/green. I have never seen such a thing before. and its on all the images.

What is going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(false)`

```
Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(url)
                .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
                .setIndicatorsEnabled(false)
                .fit().centerInside().placeholder(null)
                .into(imgView, new Callback()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess()
                    {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError()
                    {
                        Picasso.with(mContext)
                                .load(url)
                                .fit().centerInside()
                                .into(imgView, new Callback()
                                {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess()
                                    {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError()
                                    {
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                });
```

The color shows the source of image which is being displayed

**Red** color indicates that image is fetched from **network**.

**Green** color indicates that image is fetched from **cache memory**.

**Blue** color indicates that image is fetched from **disk memory**.

Comment: ah yes thanks, by the way can u tell me what are htese indicators blue green and red?