# Picasso loads image with triangle in corner of image

Tags: android, image, picasso

I'm using picasso library for loading images from server into my application. my problem is when image loaded it has a triangle in top-left corner of image with color(like blue,green,red). 
this is my code for loading image:

```
public static void loadDynamicImage(final String url, final Context context, final ImageView imageView, final int width, final int height){
    Picasso.with(context).load(url)
            .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE)
            .resize(width,height)
            .onlyScaleDown()
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(width,height).onlyScaleDown().into(imageView);
                }
            });
}
```

the image shown is : 
[image: the image that picasso loads in application]

Comment: That's either from `setDebugging(true)` or `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Picasso showing blue red and green arrows on top corner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34757949/picasso-showing-blue-red-and-green-arrows-on-top-corner)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have enabled debug indicators on your Picasso instance (see [official website](http://square.github.io/picasso/)). Look for `setIndicatorsEnabled(true)` in your code and remove it.

Answer (score 5):

You have `setIndicatorsEnabled` set to `true`

```
Picasso picasso = Picasso.with(this);
picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(false); //Or remove picasso.setIndicatorsEnabled(true);
```

Check this: [Is there any way from which we can detect images are loading from cache in picasso?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915704/is-there-any-way-from-which-we-can-detect-images-are-loading-from-cache-in-picas/34926291#34926291)